# Timer class implementation

Tags: c#, timer, async-await

I have made a timer class:

- The timer should call an async method and wait between two calls.
- I want to wake up the timer to skip the wait period.
- When I dispose the timer from outside the timer I want to wait until the current call is completed.
- I want to stop the timer from inside the timer.

```
public sealed class CompletionTimer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource disposeToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private readonly Task runTask;
    private int requiresAtLeastOne;
    private CancellationTokenSource wakeupToken;

    public CompletionTimer(int delayInMs, Func<CancellationToken, Task> callback, int initialDelay = 0)
    {
        runTask = RunInternal(delayInMs, initialDelay, callback);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        disposeToken.Cancel();

        runTask.Wait();
    }

    public void Wakeup()
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();

        Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref requiresAtLeastOne, 2, 0);

        wakeupToken?.Cancel();
    }

    private async Task RunInternal(int delay, int initialDelay, Func<CancellationToken, Task> callback)
    {
        if (initialDelay > 0)
        {
            await WaitAsync(initialDelay).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        while (requiresAtLeastOne == 2 || !disposeToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                await callback(disposeToken.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                requiresAtLeastOne = 1;
            }

            await WaitAsync(delay).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }

    private async Task WaitAsync(int intervall)
    {
        try
        {
            wakeupToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

            using (var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(disposeToken.Token, wakeupToken.Token))
            {
                await Task.Delay(intervall, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The `requiresAtLeastOne` field is to enforce at least one run when I do something like that (in a test or so):

```
var timer = new CompletionTimer(10000, ct => ... );
timer.Wakeup();
timer.Dispose();
```

It almost works perfectly, but one time (of thousand of calls) I had a deadlock in the `Dispose` method, when I was calling it from within a timer. I am more confused why it does not deadlock all the time.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit hesitant to comment on anything related to concurrency, but I'll give it a try:

- Why does `Dispose` wait for `runTask` to finish? To me, that's a rather surprising side-effect. I'd expect `Dispose` to stop the timer, and to abort the current invocation if possible, but not to block.
- Letting a callback dispose the `CompletionTimer` that's running it sounds like a bad idea - it seems like an inverted ownership situation.
- The deadlock seems fairly straightforward: `RunInternal` invokes `callback` asynchronously, so the rest of the code is registered as a continuation and will be run when `callback` finishes. However, `callback` disposes the `CompletionTimer`, which waits for `runTask` (`RunInternal`) to finish. The callback and the run task are now both waiting for each other to finish.
- If you want the callback to be able to stop the timer, perhaps changing its return type to `Task<bool>` is a better idea: the timer can then terminate its loop after the callback returns `false`.
- The `requiresAtLeastOne` construction looks a little confusing, with it being compared against a few 'magic values'. A `requiredInvocationsLeft` field that is decremented after each invocation seems a little easier to grasp - and would also allow you to configure the number of required invocations after a wake-up.
- Perhaps `SkipCurrentDelay` is a more descriptive name than `WakeUp`. `WakeUp` could be interpreted as the timer being in sleep mode (as in, it's paused, it's not periodically invoking its callback).
- You may want to document the intended behavior of your class. As my comments may show, other people likely have different assumptions about how a timer will behave.

Creating a separate `StopAndWaitForCompletionAsync` method is probably a better idea if you need to wait for the last invocation to finish.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am so confused that the deadlock never happened ;)

The timer is used internally in a polling subscription. So the owner of the subscription decides to stop the subscription, which then stop the timer. But in this case I do not have to wait for completion, so a separate method might be much better.

The reason why I do it in the dispose method is that I want I register all dependencies